In rendering, what shape should be used for decals like bullet holes to maximize performance? triangles or squares?
For an FPS game i'm making, would it be more efficient to use triangles or squares for bullet hole decals?
The bullet hole is circle textured onto a triangle or square. For a triangle, the area would be ~1.6 times that of the circle but it would only consume 3 verticies on the gpu, and would only draw a single triangle. For a square, the area would be ~1.27 times that of the circle, but it would need 6 verticies and draw 2 triangles. For the performance (framerate), I'm not sure weather to prioritize the triangle count or the amount of pixels covered by the shape.


Just a guess but I think this is dependent of the size of the object (so the distance too). If it is close/big, then the surface should matter a lot more than the number of vertices. If it is far/small, then the number of vertices might matter more (and the fact a rectangle is actually 2 primitives). Bullet holes are generally pretty small so maybe the former is better. (PS: I'm not an expert of that).

very interesting question, i'm no expert so its just my understanding. I would go with triangles, it's my understanding that all rendering is pretty much done with triangles so that's the closest you'll get to the low level renderer. And then the pixel question I think you leave up to renderer that you hope or trust to be concerned with the efficiency of pixel rendering.
